# GCM client does not receives push notification

Tags: android, push-notification, google-cloud-messaging, buddy.com

I want my Android app to receive GCM push messages from my [buddyplatform](http://buddyplatform.com/docs/Send%20Push%20Notification) backend. I have implemented the GCM client like its shown in the [android docs](https://developer.android.com/google/gcm/client.html) but I don't get any push messages on my two test devices(Android 4.2.2 original and CM mod 10.1 Android 4.2.2).
These are my permissions and changes in my `AndroidManifest.xml`:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
<uses-permission android:name=".permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.SEND" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />
<uses-permission android:name=".permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />
...
<application>
    <receiver
        android:name=".GcmBroadcastReceiver"
        android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />

            <category android:name=".gcm" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>

    <service android:name=".GcmIntentService" />
</application>
```

My `GcmIntentService`:

```
package .wop;

import android.app.IntentService;
import android.app.NotificationManager;
import android.app.PendingIntent;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.SystemClock;
import android.support.v4.app.NotificationCompat;
import android.util.Log;

import com.google.android.gms.gcm.GoogleCloudMessaging;

/**
 * This {@code IntentService} does the actual handling of the GCM message.
 * {@code GcmBroadcastReceiver} (a {@code WakefulBroadcastReceiver}) holds a
 * partial wake lock for this service while the service does its work. When the
 * service is finished, it calls {@code completeWakefulIntent()} to release the
 * wake lock.
 */
public class GcmIntentService extends IntentService {
    public static final int NOTIFICATION_ID = 1;
    private NotificationManager mNotificationManager;
    NotificationCompat.Builder builder;

    public GcmIntentService() {
        super("GcmIntentService");
    }
    public static final String TAG = "GCM Demo";

    @Override
    protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
        Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();
        GoogleCloudMessaging gcm = GoogleCloudMessaging.getInstance(this);
        // The getMessageType() intent parameter must be the intent you received
        // in your BroadcastReceiver.
        String messageType = gcm.getMessageType(intent);

        if (!extras.isEmpty()) {  // has effect of unparcelling Bundle
            /*
             * Filter messages based on message type. Since it is likely that GCM will be
             * extended in the future with new message types, just ignore any message types you're
             * not interested in, or that you don't recognize.
             */
            if (GoogleCloudMessaging.MESSAGE_TYPE_SEND_ERROR.equals(messageType)) {
                sendNotification("Send error: " + extras.toString());
            } else if (GoogleCloudMessaging.MESSAGE_TYPE_DELETED.equals(messageType)) {
                sendNotification("Deleted messages on server: " + extras.toString());
                // If it's a regular GCM message, do some work.
            } else if (GoogleCloudMessaging.MESSAGE_TYPE_MESSAGE.equals(messageType)) {
                // This loop represents the service doing some work.
                for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
                    Log.i(TAG, "Working... " + (i + 1)
                            + "/5 @ " + SystemClock.elapsedRealtime());
                    try {
                        Thread.sleep(5000);
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    }
                }
                Log.i(TAG, "Completed work @ " + SystemClock.elapsedRealtime());
                // Post notification of received message.
                sendNotification("Received: " + extras.toString());
                Log.i(TAG, "Received: " + extras.toString());
            }
        }
        // Release the wake lock provided by the WakefulBroadcastReceiver.
        GcmBroadcastReceiver.completeWakefulIntent(intent);
    }

    // Put the message into a notification and post it.
    // This is just one simple example of what you might choose to do with
    // a GCM message.
    private void sendNotification(String msg) {
        mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager)
                this.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

        PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0,
                new Intent(this, MainActivity.class), 0);

        NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder =
                new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
                        .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.common_signin_btn_icon_dark)
                        .setContentTitle("GCM Notification")
                        .setStyle(new NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle()
                                .bigText(msg))
                        .setContentText(msg);

        mBuilder.setContentIntent(contentIntent);
        mNotificationManager.notify(NOTIFICATION_ID, mBuilder.build());
    }
}
```

My `GcmBroadcastReceiver`:

```
package .wop;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.ComponentName;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v4.content.WakefulBroadcastReceiver;

public class GcmBroadcastReceiver extends WakefulBroadcastReceiver {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        System.out.println("PUSH RECEIVED!!!");
        // Explicitly specify that GcmIntentService will handle the intent.
        ComponentName comp = new ComponentName(context.getPackageName(),
                GcmIntentService.class.getName());
        // Start the service, keeping the device awake while it is launching.
        startWakefulService(context, (intent.setComponent(comp)));
        setResultCode(Activity.RESULT_OK);
    }
}
```

And the changes I did for GCM in my `MainActivity`:

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

//GCM
public static final String EXTRA_MESSAGE = "message";
public static final String PROPERTY_REG_ID = "registration_id";
private static final String PROPERTY_APP_VERSION = "appVersion";
private final static int PLAY_SERVICES_RESOLUTION_REQUEST = 9000;

/**
 * Substitute you own sender ID here. This is the project number you got
 * from the API Console, as described in "Getting Started."
 */
String SENDER_ID = "3019882...";

/**
 * Tag used on log messages.
 */
static final String TAG = "GCMDemo";

TextView mDisplay;
GoogleCloudMessaging gcm;
AtomicInteger msgId = new AtomicInteger();
SharedPreferences prefs;
Context context;

String regid;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    mDisplay = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.displayPush);
    context = getApplicationContext();

    //GCM
    // Check device for Play Services APK. If check succeeds, proceed with
    //  GCM registration.
    if (checkPlayServices()) {
        gcm = GoogleCloudMessaging.getInstance(this);
        regid = getRegistrationId(context);

        if (regid.isEmpty()) {
            registerInBackground();
        } else {
            System.out.println("regid: " + regid);
        }
    } else {
        Log.i(TAG, "No valid Google Play Services APK found.");
    }

/**
 * Registers the application with GCM servers asynchronously.
 * <p/>
 * Stores the registration ID and the app versionCode in the application's
 * shared preferences.
 */
private void registerInBackground() {
    new AsyncTask<Void, Void, String>() {
        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {
            String msg = "";
            try {
                if (gcm == null) {
                    gcm = GoogleCloudMessaging.getInstance(context);
                }
                regid = gcm.register(SENDER_ID);
                msg = "Device registered, registration ID=" + regid;
                System.out.println(msg);

                // You should send the registration ID to your server over HTTP, so it
                // can use GCM/HTTP or CCS to send messages to your app.
                sendRegistrationIdToBackend();

                // For this demo: we don't need to send it because the device will send
                // upstream messages to a server that echo back the message using the
                // 'from' address in the message.

                // Persist the regID - no need to register again.
                storeRegistrationId(context, regid);
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                msg = "Error :" + ex.getMessage();
                System.out.println(msg);
                // If there is an error, don't just keep trying to register.
                // Require the user to click a button again, or perform
                // exponential back-off.
            }
            return msg;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String msg) {
            mDisplay.append(msg + "\n");
        }
    }.execute(null, null, null);
}

/**
 * Sends the registration ID to your server over HTTP, so it can use GCM/HTTP
 * or CCS to send messages to your app. Not needed for this demo since the
 * device sends upstream messages to a server that echoes back the message
 * using the 'from' address in the message.
 */
private void sendRegistrationIdToBackend() {
    //ADDED BY MYSELF
    Buddy.setPushToken(regid, new BuddyCallback<Boolean>(Boolean.class) {

        @Override
        public void completed(BuddyResult<Boolean> result) {
            System.out.println("sendPushToken successfully");
        }
    });
}

/**
 * Stores the registration ID and app versionCode in the application's
 * {@code SharedPreferences}.
 *
 * @param context application's context.
 * @param regId   registration ID
 */
private void storeRegistrationId(Context context, String regId) {
    final SharedPreferences prefs = getGCMPreferences(context);
    int appVersion = getAppVersion(context);
    Log.i(TAG, "Saving regId on app version " + appVersion);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs.edit();
    editor.putString(PROPERTY_REG_ID, regId);
    editor.putInt(PROPERTY_APP_VERSION, appVersion);
    editor.commit();
}

/**
 * Gets the current registration ID for application on GCM service.
 * <p/>
 * If result is empty, the app needs to register.
 *
 * @return registration ID, or empty string if there is no existing
 * registration ID.
 */
private String getRegistrationId(Context context) {
    final SharedPreferences prefs = getGCMPreferences(context);
    String registrationId = prefs.getString(PROPERTY_REG_ID, "");
    if (registrationId.isEmpty()) {
        Log.i(TAG, "Registration not found.");
        return "";
    }
    // Check if app was updated; if so, it must clear the registration ID
    // since the existing regID is not guaranteed to work with the new
    // app version.
    int registeredVersion = prefs.getInt(PROPERTY_APP_VERSION, Integer.MIN_VALUE);
    int currentVersion = getAppVersion(context);
    if (registeredVersion != currentVersion) {
        Log.i(TAG, "App version changed.");
        return "";
    }
    return registrationId;
}

/**
 * @return Application's {@code SharedPreferences}.
 */
private SharedPreferences getGCMPreferences(Context context) {
    // This sample app persists the registration ID in shared preferences, but
    // how you store the regID in your app is up to you.
    return getSharedPreferences(MainActivity.class.getSimpleName(),
            Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
}

/**
 * @return Application's version code from the {@code PackageManager}.
 */
private static int getAppVersion(Context context) {
    try {
        PackageInfo packageInfo = context.getPackageManager()
                .getPackageInfo(context.getPackageName(), 0);
        return packageInfo.versionCode;
    } catch (PackageManager.NameNotFoundException e) {
        // should never happen
        throw new RuntimeException("Could not get package name: " + e);
    }
}


//GCM
// You need to do the Play Services APK check here too.
@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    checkPlayServices();
}

//GCM

/**
 * Check the device to make sure it has the Google Play Services APK. If
 * it doesn't, display a dialog that allows users to download the APK from
 * the Google Play Store or enable it in the device's system settings.
 */
private boolean checkPlayServices() {
    int resultCode = GooglePlayServicesUtil.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(this);
    if (resultCode != ConnectionResult.SUCCESS) {
        if (GooglePlayServicesUtil.isUserRecoverableError(resultCode)) {
            GooglePlayServicesUtil.getErrorDialog(resultCode, this,
                    PLAY_SERVICES_RESOLUTION_REQUEST).show();
        } else {
            Log.i(TAG, "This device is not supported.");
            finish();
        }
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

As you can see, I copy & pasted most of the code from the Android docs.
I added my `SENDER_ID` (Project Number) and implemented the method to send Buddy my PushToken.

When I start the App, the output says that the device is registered successfully with a `regid` like: `APA91bF_uwCWiurDgc...`. It also says that my google play services is valid but I don't get any push notification although my buddy dashboard tells me, that I sent a push notification successfully.

Do I have forgotten something?

Comment: so you need to test your gcm communicate service. Your gcm communicate service may wrong.This link you can test your android application.http://www.androidbegin.com/tutorial/gcm.html

Comment: Thanks for your fast comment. I've tested it and the result was: `{"multicast_id":7328710106740104328,"success":1,"failure":0,"canonical_ids":0,"results":[{"message_id":"0:1409214898016680%e98399c7f9fd7ecd"}]}`. I got this push successfully on my phone. So why don't I get push messages from the buddy platform?

Comment: that sample link is developed with PHP.

Comment: If my answer is right, accept my answer for other viewer. thank you.

Comment: @Peter How do you send notifications from buddy dashboard? as far as I have seen there is only push notification test, which works for me, but I want to sent notifications to all registered devices, not the only one I manually put.

Comment: You can do this via the console. If you need any further help just create a question, send me the link and I'll help if I can.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to test your gcm communicate service. Your gcm communicate service may be something wrong.  [This](http://www.androidbegin.com/tutorial/gcm.html) link you can test your android application that sample link is developed with PHP. If you test with that link can connect your android application, you need to modify your gcm communicate service. Hope for help.

Comment: This answer didn't really solved my problem, but I know now that it has something to do with the buddy backend and not with my GCM client.

Comment: so your gcm communicate service not wrong? you said my sample gcm communicate service can call your client android application. so i thought you need to modify your gcm communcate service. I just point of your error.

Comment: To be hontest, I really don't know what is wrong. I assumed hat my code has to be correct if it can get pushes from this website. So what do you think, what part of my code may be wrong? Sorry that i misunderstood your answer, I don't have any experience in this topic.

Comment: Ok, I really don't know why, but its working now, also with the Buddy push. Thanks for your help.

Comment: if you want to know. you should see this link http://www.androidbegin.com/tutorial/android-google-cloud-messaging-gcm-tutorial/ and google official link http://developer.android.com/google/gcm/gs.html